# How can you save images with a long press using photoswipe via mobile app?

Tags: android, image, mobile, save, photoswipe

I am creating a mobile app using photoswipe and have put together my galleries, etc. Now I would like to incorporate a way for the user to be able to longpress the image and get the option to save, wallpaper, etc. Is anyone familiar with the best way to approach this?

Comment: also interested in this, ever figure it out?

Comment: hey me too interested in the same thing. Have you figured it out. Can you please help me out with is.